# else statement is expecting an if statement after being provided one

Tags: c++

The else keyword keeps expecting an if statement when one was given. I tried double checking the brackets and looking up similar questions being asked.

````cpp
{
            
            if (imageSurface == NULL);
            std::cout << "Image failed to load" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            else
            {
                SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
                SDL_Delay(2000);

            }
            
        }```
````

Comment: Checks the `;`.

Comment: Remove the semicolon here after if (imageSurface == NULL);

Comment: if (condition) {... } else { ... }. You need the braces. If you have NO else clause, then you can use "if (condition) [your code]" without braces.

Comment: @Rethunk That's just not true

Comment: @Rethunk `if (condition) statement1; else statement2;` is a valid C++ code. No braces needed. Technically speaking: `statement1`/`statement2` _can_ be compound statement, which is denoted by multiple statements wrapped between braces.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, yes, thanks to you and Simon for catching that. Upvotes to both of your comments. My head was stuck in Swift and I wrote too hastily.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting semicolon(;) after `if` which makes the termination of if statement. Run now

```
                if (imageSurface == NULL)
                std::cout << "Image failed to load" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
                else
                {
                    SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
                    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
                    SDL_Delay(2000);
    
                }
```